# Use of unresolved identifier 'objectAtIndexPath'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I am working on an app that allows you to 'Like' posts. I was implementing the like button, but I got an error that I cannot seem to fix. 
I searched in another posts, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

This is the code I'm using to implement the like button. Do I need to import something into my project? Or unwrap at certain point?

Any help is appreciate it.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:PostTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! PostTableViewCell

    let post = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as PFObject

    cell.postTextView.alpha = 0
    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.postTextView.text = post.objectForKey("content") as! String

    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt!)

    // to get username from the post
    var showUsername:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    //the objectID is the same as the user in the two different tables
    showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId!!)

    showUsername.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            let user = (objects as! [PFUser]).last
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user!.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.postTextView.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFObject {
    return self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
}

@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    //disables the like button so it can't be pressed again
    sender.enabled = false
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false
    sender.alpha = 0.5

    //get the point in the table view that corresponds to the button that was pressed
    //in my case these were a bunch of cells each with their own like button
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = self.objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex!) as PFObject

    //this is where I incremented the key for the object
    object.incrementKey("likes")
    object.saveInBackground() //still gives me error here

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
}
```

**Update2:** Added a photo of the error
[image: Error]

Comment: what is objectAtIndexPath supposed to be?

Comment: It returns an object at a particular indexPath, which in this case is the `hitIndex` since the like button is in each of the users posts, so it just selects only that 'like' for that specific post

Comment: Why did you use a question mark?

Comment: Just for clarity sake - is this class inheriting from `NSFetchedResultsController`? I couldn't find any other class with `objectAtIndexPath` method. If it is not, did you provide implementation for this method? If yes, please show it.

Comment: Originally didn't have one, but still gave me an error, so sometimes I have fixed errors by unwrapping, but didn't work this time. I'm going to edit it to revert it back to original.

Comment: @Losiowaty it is not inheriting from `NSFetchedResultsController`. I will post my complete class now

Comment: @Losiowaty just posted my whole class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the view controller is neither an `NSFetchedResultsController` or a `PFQueryTableViewController`, you'll have to implement `objectAtIndexPath:` yourself.

A hint about the code you need is in cellForRowAtIndexPath':

```
let post:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject
```

Dispensing with the objectAtIndex method on array, just index into the array at the row:

```
func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFObject {
    return self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
}
```

Call it wherever the old code appears like this (in likeButton)...

```
let object = self.objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex) as! PFObject
```

or, in cellForRowAtIndexPath:...

```
let post = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as!PFObject
```

etc.

Comment: return 'that' you mean, return `objectAtIndexPath` from the `tableView` function? or?

Comment: yes.  `return self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)`

Comment: okay I did that, but I still have the error, and I'm a little confused about what I'm doing

Comment: Yeah - I'm not very swift conversant, but I don't see the method objectAtIndexPath on an array in swift.  But the idea is the same as indexing into it.  Please see edit for modified answer.

Comment: Okay so I tried it out and it worked, the error is gone. I had to changed it to: `return self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as! PFObject` or else it would've given me an error, but now, it's not saving the likes in the background. I got an error that `object.saveInBackground()` doesn't have a member called `saveInBackground()`

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, I'm still new to swift, and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I'm new to swift, too.  We know that PFObject *does* have a method saveInBackground(), right.  So the compiler must not understand that object is a PFObject.  I think you should consistently qualify the type on the assignments.  Please see edit.

Comment: Added updated code. Still gives me an error in that specific like, even after adding that `let object = self.objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex) as! PFObject`

Comment: I don't see "self." in the updated code (let object = self....).  And the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath looks the same.  Please double check that you call the method on self the way I suggest.

Comment: Yeah.  That looks right to me.  If it's still not compiling then we've exhausted my swift knowledge.  Sorry I wasn't able to help you fix it.

Comment: I added a photo of the error so you can see what it still says. 
And no worries you helped me enough to be able to click on the like button. It's just now not updating because of the `saveInBackground()`

Comment: Hey! It works now! I replaced: `saveInBackground()` with: `object.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)` and it shows on the parse database. Now I just gotta work on one like per user because after the refresh, it lets users vote for the post again lol

Comment: So I found another way of making the `saveInBackground()` work just by itself. Besides `import Parse` in the header of your class, you also gotta add `import Bolts` and that should do the trick. Just thought that I should mention in in case other users get stuck with the same problem as I did.